# How to install Ubuntu server to Raspberry Pi 2 using BTRFS?

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu, btrfs

I would like to install a Ubuntu server to my Raspi 2's SD CARD, but using btrfs file system.
The [preinstalled Ubuntu images](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) do not help in this case, how would you do this?

Comment: Why? And did you try searching the web for `btrfs ubuntu raspberry pi`? because I found this, which likely helps you: https://ferrario.me/ubuntu-on-the-raspberry-pi-part-i-installing-ubuntu-20.04-with-btrfs-on-root/

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi (Part I): Installing Ubuntu 20.04 with Btrfs on root](https://ferrario.me/ubuntu-on-the-raspberry-pi-part-i-installing-ubuntu-20.04-with-btrfs-on-root/)

Another link: [Ubuntu Desktop 20.04: installation guide with btrfs-luks full disk](https://mutschler.dev/linux/ubuntu-btrfs-20-04/)